# Given an irrational algebraic integer $x$ in a cubic field, by what algebraic integers in that field must $x$ be multiplied to get a rational integer?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

For example, given $x = \sqrt[3]{2}$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})}$, it's obvious that $x^3 = 2$. This also works: $x (-\sqrt[3]{2})^2$.

But what happens when $x$ gets a little more "complicated"? For example, $x = 1 + \sqrt[3]{2}$? Or $x = 1 + \sqrt[3]{2} + 4 (\sqrt[3]{2})^2$? I've tried multiplying these by my guesses at "conjugates" (don't know if such a thing even exists in a cubic field), like $(1 + \sqrt[3]{2})(1 - \sqrt[3]{2})(-1 + \sqrt[3]{2})$ but have only confused myself further.

(NOTE: I first posted this on MathOverflow. I was told it doesn't belong there, so I will be deleting it from there).

Comment: The product of the roots of $a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$ is equal to the $a_0$, upto sign.

Comment: So you need the minimal polynomial of the given $x$ and you have to find the roots of this minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe conjugates of $x$ do not belong to the field $K=\mathbb{Q}(x)$, however, they belong to some extension of it. Since the extension is cubic, the minimal polynomial of $x$ has degree 3, so that $x$ has exactly two other conjugates $x'$ and $x''$. Then Vieta's formula tells you that $x\cdot (x'x'')$ is a rational integer, and clearly $(x'x'') \in K$.

Comment: Applying your remarks to one of David's examples, I get: $$(1 + \root 3 \of 2)(1 - \root 3 \of 2 + (\root 3 \of 2)^2) = 3.$$

Comment: Fascinating. My first instinct was $N(1 + \sqrt[3]{2}) = 3$, but my second instinct was that that's wrong.